# How can I run a 2 layers batch SWF decompiling process? I am using Sothinkswf decompiler

Tags: flash, swf-decompiler

I am decompiling a number of SWFs. Each SWF has a number of frames in it, and each frame comes out as a single SWF. I need to decompile each frame SWF to get to the information I am looking for. Is there a command to do that in Sothinkswf decompiler?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To better help the community assist you with your question, please let us know what you've tried so far that hasn't worked, and what kind of information you're expecting to get when decompling your SWF files. Any relevant code samples or example links that you can post would also be a big help.

Comment: What I did so far is: Did a first round to decompile the main SWF and break into Frames(each frame comes out as a separate SWF), Then run a batch decompile on the folder that contains frames' SWFs. I am trying to convert old E-Learning course to modern format, by decompiling the frames SWFs' I get the objects in each frame and their position and the time each Object need to show on screen which allow me to rebuild the course in the new platform but .the Problem is that I need to do that for more than 300 E-learning courses. Unfortunately I don't have a public link to demo this process